# searching phone number using AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

I have a doubt on how to search for phone number using searchbox using ajax? The following is the coding for the above issue.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function($){
    $('#query').keyup(function(){
        var search=$(this).val();
        if(search != '' & search.length >= 3 ){
            $.ajax({
                url:'search.php',
                data:'search='+search+'action=search_number',
                type:'POST',
                cache:false,
                success:function(html){
                    $("#result_search").html(html).show();
                }
            });
        }else{ $("#result_search").fadeOut(); return false;}

    });
    jQuery('#result_search').on('click',function(e){
        var $clicked = $(e.target);
        var $name = $clicked.find('.city').html();
        var decoded = $("<div/>").html($name).text();
        $('#query').val(decoded);
    });
    jQuery(document).on("click",function(e){
        var $clicked = $(e.target);
        if (! $clicked.hasClass("search")){
            $("#result_search").fadeOut(); 
        }
    });
    $('#query').click(function(e){
        var result_search= $("#results_search").html();
        var search=$('#query').val();
        if(result_search != 'No Contacts Found' && result_search != '' && search != ''){
            $("#result_search").fadeIn();
        }
    });


});
```

```
<form method = "post" action="search.php" class = "pull-down  navbar-search">
   <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" value="" name="query" id="query" placeholder="Search phone number or email" class="form-control">
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
                </div>
            </div>
   </form>
```

It shows the searchbox as following image.
[image]

Already I did the same for searching the city like the above method. Like the image below, I want the searching of phone number too.

[image]

If we type numbers on the searchbox, it should search and display the result for each number matches.

I get value from the database.
Can anyone help in this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are making your AJAX call, you are not passing the `data` attribute correctly. You are passing:

```
data:'search='+search+'action=search_number',
```

Where it should be:

```
data:'search='+search+'&action=search_number',
```

Notice the addition of the `&` to separate parameters.

Alternatively, you can pass your data as an object literal and let jQuery do it for you:

```
data: {
    search: search,
    action: 'search_number'
}
```